# Display UniSharp/laravel-filemanager inside a page (without Editor)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-manager

I'm using L5.2 and have integrated this package:
https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager

I want to create a Media page which will show the File Manager. Admin will be able to view, upload, delete or rename images on this page using File Manager.

I have integrated your filemanager successfully, but cannot find a way to display File Manager inside a page. I want to do something like Wordpress's Media page, a dedicated page for File Manager / Media.

Just to show an example, this is what I'm trying to do:

[image: Just a photoshopped picture to give you an idea.]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<iframe>` to embed the file manager in the section of your site

Eg:

```
@section('content')
    <iframe src="{{ url('laravel-filemanager') }}" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; overflow: hidden; border: none;"></iframe>
@endsection
```

You could see the usage of iframe if you'd check out the code [here](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/blob/master/src/views/demo.blade.php#L54) to embed the file manager.

Comment: how can i get the image path from that